# kendo grid numeric textbox editor value change not updating model

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui-angular2

I am using numeric text box as an editor in my grid, when I change number by applying spinner,  and then I click CRUD update button,  model is not updated with the changed value, which I observed in "save" event of grid.
Is this a bug with Kendo? Although, it will work when we add trigger to spin event, but if we edit number typing in, it wont save? Any thoughts

And wierd thing is when after we enter number and click outside and then clicking update will save correctly. why its behaving like that?

```
positiveNumberEditor: function(container, options) {
        $('<input data-bind="value:' + options.field + '"/>')
          .appendTo(container)
          .kendoNumericTextBox(
            { 
                format: " "
                ,min: 0
                ,max:9999
                ,step:1
                ,value:" "
               , spin:function (e) {
                    this.trigger("change");
                 }

            }
        );

    }
```

Comment: Is this forum active? sad to see any replies!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got answer for this.
(Answering here, so that it may help some one else!!!)

Well this is a shortcoming when we use an editable grid with reordering functionality. And hence easy fix could be adding a filter to avoid any editable row if any using css as below. And this filter is a config under kendoSortable setting of your grid.

filter: ">tbody >tr:not(.k-grid-edit-row)"